# page not found for single-type.php file in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i have created custom post type 'event' to display in single page named single-event.php file but it provides me 404 error. how i can solve this problem even i used

> flush_rewrite_rules();

Please help me to solve my problem... here is my code..

```
function custom_event() {
$labels = array( 
'name' => _x('Event', 'post type general name'),
'singular_name' => _x('Event', 'post type singular name'),
'add_new' => _x('Add Event', 'Content'),
'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event'),
'edit_item' => __('Edit Event'),
'new_item' => __('New Content'),
'view_item' => __('View Event'),
'search_items' => __('Search Content'),
'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'), 
'parent_item_colon' => '',
'menu_name' => __('Event')
 );

 $args = array(
 'labels' => $labels,
 'public' => true,
 'publicly_queryable' => true,
 'show_ui' => true, 
 'show_in_menu' => true,  
 'query_var' => true,
 'rewrite' => true,
 'capability_type' => 'post',
 'has_archive' => true, 
 'hierarchical' => false,
 'menu_position' => 20,
 'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor')
  );

  flush_rewrite_rules();
  register_post_type('event', $args); 
  }
  //$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
  //add_action('admin_init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');
   add_action ('init', 'custom_event');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event' )` instead of `'rewrite' => true`.

Also, you shouldn't use `flush_rewrite_rules()` like this. It will run unnecessarily each time. You could make a plugin to define the custom post type and flush the rewrite rules using `register_activation_hook`.